# boto3 aws ec2 status/instance check fail email script

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Hi I am trying to run a schedule script, not via lambda but from a pc or onsite schedule job - maybe every 10 mins or so to check all my ec2 instances are failing any system/instance status checks. If it fails then send email of the ec2 instance that failing - just send the name. Do not reboot

so here is what i have

```
import boto3
import smtplib


region_name='us-west-1'
#ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

#response = ec2_client.describe_instance_status(IncludeAllInstances = True)
client = boto3.client("ec2")
clientsns = boto3.client("sns")
#response = clientsns.create_topic

status = client.describe_instance_status(IncludeAllInstances = True)
#for instance in response['InstanceStatuses']:
#  instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
#  system_status = instance['SystemStatus']
#  instance_status = instance['InstanceStatus']
#  print (instance_id, system_status, instance_status)
for i in status["InstanceStatuses"]:
        print("AvailabilityZone :", i["AvailabilityZone"])
        print("InstanceId :", i["InstanceId"])
        print("InstanceState :", i["InstanceState"])
        print("InstanceStatus", i["InstanceStatus"])
        print("SystemStatus", i["SystemStatus"])
        in_status = i['InstanceStatus']['Details'][0]['Status']
        sys_status = i['SystemStatus']['Details'][0]['Status']
        msg1 = 'The following instances failed status checks, i[{InstanceId}]'
        msg2 = 'All Instances passed System/instance checks!'

        # check statuses
        if ((in_status != 'passed') or (sys_status != 'passed')):
             print(bcolors.WARNING + 'Reboot required for', i["InstanceId"] + bcolors.ENDC)
             clientsns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:462518063038:test',Message=msg1)
        else:
            print('All Instances passed System/instance checks!')
            clientsns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:462518063038:test',Message=msg2)
```

The problem I have is its sending one message per instance. I just wwant to sent one email for all instances. any idea?

Thank you

Comment: also my line clientsns.publish(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:462518063038:test',Message=msg1) is not printing out my instanceID

Comment: Because you have sent mail action in the loop that's why you get sent email every iteration. Create list / dictionary and send after loop finishes. This is what I would do. I'm not developer so I may be wrong :D